# Partial Styles coming for bootstrap tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am getting partial styles when I am trying to use bootstrap tooltip in the code. The following tool tip is coming while hovering over the standard residential info icon.
The code is right and the I have initialized the js also.
Ignore the tool tip content.

```
<i class = "fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-bind = "attr:{title:$data.toolTip}"></i>
```

And the initialization:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

[image]

Comment: Can you write whats value of `$data.toolTip` ?

Comment: it is what is coming as content  "System error...."